# Why do people use "..." in emails after people's names? For example, "Mike... "

Tags: punctuation, orthography, writing-style, ellipses

What does this "..." mean in emails? For example,

> "Mike...You are always welcome to come to our social event."

Comment: The usage you've given looks like `...` has replaced `,` or `:`. I'd probably write it `Mike, you are always welcome` etc.

Comment: Ellipses are a convenient way to say "blah, blah, you know what I mean - I'm too lazy to write the whole chunk here." Or "Mike, {are you paying attention? I know you are not}, please respond to our invitation." Or, "Mike {were you offended the last party we had? Anyway, I promise you this time will be different}, please come to our party."

Answer (score 5):

Because they do not know proper punctuation? 
At first I thought you were asking about the use of quotation marks but now I understand that you mean the ellipses, correct?

I don't know that there is a real reason for this. In my opinion it is a less formal punctuation than using a comma after "Mike" but it is in no sense standard.

The alternatives may seem too formal, (comma) or too imperative (no punctuation after Mike) so the ellipses "..." is a way to "soften" the tone in a friendly way.